# Можно ли узнать что по ссылке находится видео?

Tags: php, видео

В скрипт поступает текст внутри которого могут быть ссылки. 
Если обычная ссылка то никаких действий предпринимать не нужно а если ссылка на видео(ютуб, vk, twiter и много другого) то нужно заключать ссылку в `iframe`
Посредством php можно распознать то что в ссылке будет видео????

Comment: why not? скрипт риал тайм? если нет то парсить ссылку по маске(кам)

Comment: Не начав скачивать файл по ссылке и не посмотрев его содержимое сказать что это такое невозможно. Как минимум надо увидеть заголовок Content-type который возвращается при начале скачивания файла

Comment: $url = 'https://link_to_video;
$file = fopen($url, 'r');
$meta = stream_get_meta_data($file);
Пытался делать так то но Content-type пишет что htm/text хотя видео

Comment: А может у вас ссылки на страницы содержащие видео, а не само видео ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно отправить HEAD-запрос для каждой ссылки. В результате будут получены все заголовки для ресурса(абсолютно те же, как если бы ресурс был запрошен GET-методом), но **без контента**. Среди полученных заголовков проверять `Content-type`.

Не забывать обрабатывать ответы, содержащие редирект(code=30x).

Пример определения типа контента у ресурса, с использованием расширения [cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)

```
<?php
$url = "http://example.com/foo/bar";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec ($ch);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $contentType;
```

Comment: возвращает text/html. Я так понимаю это из-за того что ссылка не на само видео а на проигрыватель с видео(

Comment: я не уверен, что есть решение которое позволяет сделать детектор таких ссылок для **любых** сервисов видео-хостинга. Советую посмотреть в сторону готовых решений, которые уже поддерживают некоторый список сервисов видео-хостинга  и содержат обвязку для добавления в них новых. Например: [ricardofiorani/php-video-url-parser](https://packagist.org/packages/ricardofiorani/php-video-url-parser)